# how to add social login option in wordpress

Tags: login, social-connect

I want to add social login ( facebook , twitter, google) in my WordPress website.
Can you tell me how to do it in proper and easy way.
Thanks

Comment: the easiest way is to use a plugin from wordpress.org: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Social+login/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Social+login/)

Comment: What is process of adding facebook twitter like plugins has option of add facebook app id (that I don't have and don't know how to get it) can you please suggest a tutorial for this

Comment: The Facebook app id or the Twitter app id is only a other word for an API key.
In the official documentation you will find instructions how to get the respective API key.

[Twitter app id](https://partners.twitter.com/en/about-the-program/where-can-I-find-app-id.html) and [Facebook app id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register)